# Simplifying $ \sqrt{1+\cos\theta}\sqrt{1-\cos\theta} $

Tags: geometry, trigonometry

I'm trying to simplify this expression

$$
\sqrt{1+\cos\theta}\sqrt{1-\cos\theta} 
$$
I suspect the expression to equal ($-\sin\theta$). Direct calculation yields same result but I couldn't reach to a proof. I've tried to use half‐angle identities but it takes me back to the original formula.

Comment: $\sqrt{1+\cos\theta}\sqrt{1-\cos\theta} = \sqrt{1-\cos^2\theta} = \ldots$?

Comment: Each square root gives a nonnegative number.  How could the product of two nonnegative numbers be $- \sin \theta$, which is negative half the time?

Comment: Which “direct calculation” yields the same result? For what values of $\theta$? What about $\theta  = \pi/2$?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have\begin{align}\sqrt{1+\cos\theta}\sqrt{1-\cos\theta}&=\sqrt{(1+\cos\theta)(1-\cos\theta)}\\&=\sqrt{1-\cos^2\theta}\\&=\sqrt{\sin^2\theta}\\&=|\sin\theta|.\end{align}